# Showing progress bar when waiting on chooser

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have app which share images in another applications. But sometimes it takes a while to load chooser to pick app which will share it. So I want ask if there is some simple way to add some progress bar when loading chooser.
My code for sharing:

```
  private void share(Uri uri, String format) {
    try { Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri); 
        shareIntent.setType("image/"+format);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That would be difficult to accomplish (to `dismiss()` especially), and IMHO a waste of time. Don't play around with a `ProgressBar` `AlertDialog` or something just because a device is slow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finaly found solution. I just show progress bar when calling share function and hiding it in onPause - pause is called in moment chooser is on screen. Hope it will help someone.